# scp tranfer can't be done bothways. lost connection

Tags: networking, port, file-transfer, scp

I'm trying to transfer a file via ssh but it works only from PC1 to PC2 but it doesn't work backwards.

My recievers firewall is disabled

I've checked my ssh_config files and both are the same. Which is basic:

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts 
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Because i've also trying adding this to the recievers `ssh_config`

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
Port 22
Protocol 2, 1
```

And it still doesn't work.

Here's my I/O

```
:~# scp -v testFile.txt user@192.168.1.67:/home
```

> ```
> Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.67, user root, command scp -v -t /home
> OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> debug1: Applying options for *
> debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.67 [192.168.1.67] port 22.
> debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection refused
> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection refused
> lost connection
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is sshd running on both hosts? Do you have some NAT-box between the hosts?

Comment: @Kride SShd is running on both hosts. I checked it with `ps aux | grep sshd` And there's nothing between the hosts ..

Comment: Adding more verbosity might give some clue. Try "scp -vvv" or "ssh -vvv"

Comment: Does plain simple `ssh` also fail with `Connection refused` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the `ssh_config` .

The problem was in the `sshd_config`

There, to access with password, just enabled the line

`PasswordAuthentication yes`

Then, restarted the ssh service

That was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied your public key to 192.168.1.67? If not you need to enable PasswordAuthentication. It should be "yes", if you like to use a password.

Comment: I've enabled passAuth and i'm having the same problem...